# Convert List of numbers to List of String

Tags: javascript, dictionary

Why does the following thing is not working in Javascript ?

```
> var a = [1, 2, 3]
undefined
> a.map(toString)
["[object Undefined]", "[object Undefined]", "[object Undefined]"]
```

But this works:

```
> a[1].toString()
"2"
```

Comment: What particular output do you want? Or are you just asking why that approach fails?

Comment: My expected output: `["1", "2", "3"]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`toString` is not a function that takes an argument, it is a method of the global object, but methods are not [bound by default in JS](http://fitzgeraldnick.com/weblog/26/).

```
a.map(function (x) { return x.toString(); })
```

will do what you want, as will

```
a.map(String)
```

since the `String` constructor when called as a function coerces its argument to a string.

Answer (score 4):

You're trying to call the  `window.toString` function and the `Number.prototype` one would have to be applied with the number as receiver.

The simpler solution is to use the `String` constructor :

```
 a.map(String)
```

Comment: `toString` does exist (`function toString() { [native code] }`), but I can't find it in the documentation.

Comment: @Blender Maybe the window one ?

Comment: @Blender: It's actually `window.toString`.